# Google ReCaptcha - Verifying in VB .NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, recaptcha

I'm trying to use the new ReCaptcha code on a simple form.

- I've signed up with one domain, the one required for the live version
  of the form.
- I've got the form to display the ReCaptcha box fine...    at first I
  just had to tick the box, now as I keep using it, it    prompts to
  enter the displayed text.  This suggests it's working    correctly.

The problem is getting the response at submit.

If I enter the URL by hand

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}
```

...where {0} is my secret key and {1} is the result of Request.Form("g-recaptcha-response") then it works.

If I use this code (pinched from t'net):

```
Dim GoogleReply = Client.DownloadString(String.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}", PrivateKey, EncodedResponse))
```

...then it stalls with a timeout.

Is there anything wrong with the code?  Or anything further I need to do to let the server side code get a response?

Comment: You can see how I did this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515838/new-google-recaptcha-with-asp-net

Comment: Steve,  it's great that it's a complete solution (I hadn't coded the test for success yet), but sadly I'm still getting the timeout error.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Steve's code (see above) and also found I needed to use a proxy to allow the in-code request to get through to the web.... so I've added some additional code (the extra variables area all assigned from the web.config)

```
                If Trim(strUseJHProxy) = "1" Then
                    Dim proxy As New System.Net.WebProxy(strJHProxyURL, False)
                    proxy.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(strNetworkUserName, strNetworkUserPassword, strNetworkUserDomain)
                    request.Proxy = proxy
                End If
```

It's now working :)   Thanks Steve!